# Interpolation using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, interpolation, polynomials

I'm having trouble on doing a homework exercise.

I need to describe an efficient algorithm which solves the [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) problem:

1. Let `P[i,j]` be the polynomial interpolation of the points (xi, yi),...,(xj,yj). Find 3 simple polynomials q(x), r(x), s(x) of degree 0 or 1 such that:

   `P[i,j+1]={q(x)P[i,j](x)-r(x)P[i+1,j+1](x)}/s(x)`
2. Given the points (x1,y1),....(xn,yn), describe an efficient dynamic programming algorithm based on the recurrence relation which you found in section 1 for computing the coefficients a0,...an-1 of the polynomial interpolation.

Well, I know how to solve the polynomial interpolation problem using [Newton polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) which looks quite similar to the above recurrence relation but I don't see how it helps me to find q(x), r(x), s(x) of degree 0 or 1, and assuming I have the correct q(x), r(x), s(x)- how do I solve this problem using dynamic programming?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
q(x) = (x at {j+1}) - x
r(x) = (x at i) - x
s(x) = (x at {j+1}) - (x at i)
```

`x at i` or `x at j` mean their place in the ordered list of input points.

Some explanations:

First we need to understand what `P[i,j](x)` means.

Put all your initial `(x,y)` pairs in the main diagonal of an `n x n` matrix.
Now you can extract `P[0,0](x)` to be the y value of the point in your matrix at `(0,0)`.
`P[0,1]` is the linear interpolation of the points in your matrix at `(0,0)` and `(1,1)`. This will be a straight line function.

```
((x at 0 - x)(y at 1) - (x at 1 - x)(y at 0)) 
---------------------------------------------
              (x at 1 - x at 0)
```

`P[0,2]` is the linear interpolation of two previous linear interpolations, which means that your `y`s now will be the linear functions which you calculated at the previous step.
This is also the dynamic algorithm which builds the full polynom.

I highly recommend you have a look at [this](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp360/lectures/Lagra.pdf) very good lecture, and the full [lecture notes](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp360/lectures/LagrangeText.pdf).

Comment: The links to the reccomended lecture in the answer are broken. Here are updated ones that works:
https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp360/lectures/old/Lagra.pdf
https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp360/lectures/old/LagrangeText.pdf